# How to remove or access the build timestamp of a plugin in the pom file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, plugins, pom.xml

I have a **eclipse plugin with pom file** which after building in jenkins, provides the jar in following format:
**abc.xyz_1.2.3.201909251020.jar**.

The product which I am build is eclipse based product(Plugin-development)

**Requirement is either of the below:**

1. Build that plugin with no time stamp so that it will look like: **abc.xyz_1.2.3.jar**
2. Get the timestamp "201909251020" in my pom file through any variable.

It will be helpful if I can get some help on it.Thank you.

**Note1:**

xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd are used in the pom file.

**Note2:**

The plugins are built using org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:1.4.0:package-plugin

Comment: A plugin for what (Eclipse, Maven, ...)? How exactly is it built?

Comment: Does your jar really have underscores `_` in its name?

Comment: @JF Meier, yes.

Comment: Please check your jenkins file where this timestamps could be appended from there not in the POM file